# how to install alpine on CentOS with Yum?

Tags: centos, yum, repository, administration, alpine-mail

How do I update/refresh or add repos to Yum to install the alpine mail client?

```
thufir@arrakis:~ $ 
thufir@arrakis:~ $ ll /etc/yum.repos.d/
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2139 Sep 28  2013 CentOS-Base.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  718 May 31  2013 CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  630 May 31  2013 CentOS-Media.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3664 May 31  2013 CentOS-Vault.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  293 May 31  2013 schmooze.repo
thufir@arrakis:~ $ 
thufir@arrakis:~ $ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
thufir@arrakis:~ $ 
thufir@arrakis:~ $ yum search alpine
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: centos.eecs.wsu.edu
 * extras: mirror.spro.net
 * updates: mirror.hostduplex.com
schmooze-commercial                                                                                                          171/171
Warning: No matches found for: alpine
No Matches found
thufir@arrakis:~ $
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do:

```
$ sudo yum install epel-release
$ sudo yum install alpine
```

The 1st one adds EPEL to your repository list, and EPEL provides alpine.

**NOTE:** Also make sure that the repo is enabled in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`:

```
enabled=1
```

Or from the command line:

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
```